# Plotting output voltages from a Wheatstone Bridge Circuit

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Why does my plot have all these lines from the origin to the main curve? I am plotting the output voltage from a Wheatstone bridge circuit with the upper and lower lines representing the discrepancy caused by resistor tolerances.

[image: MATLAB Plot]]
Here is my code:

```
A=13.5;
R1=40;
R2=40;
R3=40;
R4=40;
Vref=5;
Vout1=zeros(size(0:0.01:0.25));
Vout2=zeros(size(0:0.01:0.25));
Vout3=zeros(size(0:0.01:0.25));
avector=zeros(size(0:0.01:0.25));
n=0;
for a=0:0.01:0.35
    n=n+1;
    avector(1,n)=a;
    Vout1(1,n)=(A*a*Vref)/(4*(1+a/2));
    Vout2(1,n)=(A*Vref)*(((1.01*R1)/(1.01*R1+0.99*R2))-((0.99*R3)/(0.99*R3+(1+a)*1.01*R4)));
    Vout3(1,n)=(A*Vref)*(((0.99*R1)/(0.99*R1+1.01*R2))-((1.01*R3)/(1.01*R3+(1+a)*0.99*R4)));
    plot(avector,Vout1)
    hold on
    plot(avector,Vout2)
    hold on
    plot(avector,Vout3)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the line `hold off` to the end of your loop to reset the axes properties, otherwise MATLAB will try to connect everything from the starting point of Vout1 to every point in Vout1, Vout2, and Vout3

```
A=13.5;
R1=40;
R2=40;
R3=40;
R4=40;
Vref=5;
Vout1=zeros(size(0:0.01:0.25));
Vout2=zeros(size(0:0.01:0.25));
Vout3=zeros(size(0:0.01:0.25));
avector=zeros(size(0:0.01:0.25));
n=0;
for a=0:0.01:0.35
    n=n+1;
    avector(1,n)=a;
    Vout1(1,n)=(A*a*Vref)/(4*(1+a/2));
    Vout2(1,n)=(A*Vref)*(((1.01*R1)/(1.01*R1+0.99*R2))-((0.99*R3)/(0.99*R3+(1+a)*1.01*R4)));
    Vout3(1,n)=(A*Vref)*(((0.99*R1)/(0.99*R1+1.01*R2))-((1.01*R3)/(1.01*R3+(1+a)*0.99*R4)));
    plot(avector,Vout1)
    hold on
    plot(avector,Vout2)
    plot(avector,Vout3)
    % add this line
    hold off
end
```

[image]

Comment: ***1.*** `#` is not for comments in MATLAB. ***2.*** Multiple calls to `hold on` are unnecessary.